# How to create a regex to verify the linux path and allow variables to be used

Tags: javascript, linux

How to create a regular expression to verify the linux path and allow variables in the path

```
like: $JOB_Name/WORKSPACE/bin
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I'm afraid you will need to rephrase that. I have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: add sample input and output cases, explain exactly what you are trying to do